.NET 8 COM class using GeneratedComInterfaceAttribute not visible to VB6/VBA or OLEViewer
Following the Source generation for ComWrappers article from Microsoft, I've created a simple .NET 8 Class Library project in Visual Studio 2022 using the GeneratedComInterfaceAttribute attribute, with the intent of using this library in VB6.
My class is based on a similar class described in this other Stack Overflow question where .NET 5 is used.
This is the code for the default Class1.cs:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshalling;

namespace ComHostTest
{
    [GeneratedComClass]
    [Guid("63C60D62-317F-4BAB-BB20-0AB41F34A345")]
    public partial class Class1
    {
        public string SayHello() => "Hello World from .NET " + RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
    }
}

This is my project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
        <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

My build configuration and PlatformTarget are set for x86. The project builds properly and generates a ComHostTest.comhost.dll:

Using an elevated command prompt, I successfully registered the comhost.dll:


Then, using either the VB6 IDE's References window or the OLEViewer, I do not see the ComHostTest assembly as an available COM type library:


Any idea why?
I have read this very similar question where the person uses .NET 8 also but not the GeneratedComInterfaceAttribute.

Edit
I adjusted my code following Simon Mourier's comments:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComHostTest
{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("72433A8C-941E-4876-8CC2-15F6F4235F32")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IComHostTest
    {
        public string SayHello();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("63C60D62-317F-4BAB-BB20-0AB41F34A345")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class ComHostTest : IComHostTest
    {
        public string SayHello() => "Hello World from .NET " + RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
    }

}

The project file was not touched since it already included <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>.
I downloaded the dscom32 release from GitHub and then, from the Developer PowerShell window in Visual Studio, I executed the following command:
dscom32 tlbexport "D:\.NET Projects\Development\COM host\ComHostTest\bin\x86\Debug\net8.0\ComHostTest.dll"

This generated a ComHostTest TLB file which I included in my .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
        <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ComHostTypeLibrary Include="ComHostTest.tlb" Id="1" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Still no luck seeing it in the VB6 IDE but I must be close.

Did you try exactly following the example in the article? Did you look in the registry to see if the changes you expected showed up after you registered your code? The article says that those tools don't support dual interfaces. Does VB6 even recognize IUnknown-only objects? Sorry, it's been 20 years since I touched any of this (closer to 25 since I was fluent)

@Flydog57 not exactly, I didn't create an interface, just a class. There is nothing in the Registry for ComHostTest or the GUID I used.

@Flydog57 this question leads me to believe that VB6 does support IUnknown-only objects.

You have two problems 1) with source generator, you must define an interface and a class as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/comwrappers-source-generation#basic-usage and 2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib1090-1099 .NET COM hosting with EnableComHosting only supports built-in COM interop. It does not support source-generated COM interop with GeneratedComInterfaceAttribute. If you want to enable COM hosting just don't use the newer source generation constructs. Unrelated to VB/VBA

@SimonMourier Built-in COM interop means I have to import the DLL with ComImport or DllImport afterwards? This would only work with .NET projects? I'd create a COM DLL using .NET and load it in a .NET project? Sounds like translating English to Chinese and then back to English no?

Well, what it means is you cannot currently combine EnableComHosting with generated ComWrappers (GeneratedComXXX attributes). Just stick with the ComImport interfaces way, generated ComWrappers is not strictly required, it's just a newer way (presumably better but it's a bit a work in progress...) of doing thing that enable scenarios like AOT, but you don't need this to expose to VB6. My answer in your link for .NET 5 is still valid for .NET 8. You can also combine with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78308516/403671

@SimonMourier I edited my question and compiled the project again. I tried running dscom after that. dscom works but dscom32 is not recognized. My OS is x64 but my DLL was compiled for x86. Do I need to run dscom32 or should dscom be fine?

dcscom does not work (same message as you) and dscom32 works fine for me. You're probably not pointing at an x86 dll

@SimonMourier installing dscom using dotnet tool install --global dscom didn't install dscom32 but I was able to find a compiled version on GitHub. I was able to generate a TLB file so I am happy to steer clear of MIDL.

yes I use dscom & dscom32 releases directly from github

Following Simon Mourier's comments and his answer on this similar question, I have managed to get the library to show up in VB6's References list.
Writing the interfaces and classes
First, the easy part. Here is the code for the interface and class:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace ComHostTest
    {
    
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [Guid("72433A8C-941E-4876-8CC2-15F6F4235F32")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public interface IComHostTest
        {
            public string SayHello();
        }
    
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [Guid("63C60D62-317F-4BAB-BB20-0AB41F34A345")]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        public class ComHostTest : IComHostTest
        {
            public string SayHello() => "Hello World! from .NET " + RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
        }
    
    }

You can use the Create GUID window in Visual Studio (Tools > Create GUID) to generate new values for the Guid() attributes.
The project file (.csproj):
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
        <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Set the project platform to x86 in the Configuration Manager. This will compile a 32-bit DLL which is what VB6 expects.
You should be able to build this project and get a ComHostTest.comhost.dll. This is a COM server:

A COM server is any object that provides services to clients; these
services are in the form of COM interface implementations that can be
called by any client that is able to get a pointer to one of the
interfaces on the server object.

Register this DLL using regsvr32. This writes the IComHostTest and ComHostTest GUIDs to the Windows registry. From an elevated Command Prompt:
regsvr32 ComHostTest.comhost.dll

At this point, you can activate your COM class from a .NET project using [ComImport] and [CoClass] attributes, but we need to go further for VB6 to recognize the class.
Creating and Registering TLB
For VB6 to reference your assembly, you first need to create a type library file (TLB) for it. If you don't already have it, get dscom32.exe from GitHub. You can get the compiled version from dSPACE-group/dscom Releases. This tool will generate a TLB file from your DLL:
dscom32 tlbexport "D:\.NET Projects\Development\COM host\ComHostTest\bin\x86\Debug\net8.0\ComHostTest.dll"

You now have a TLB for your assembly.
To save you from manually running the command, you can set up a Build Task to create the TLB file automatically at compile time. You will need to add the dSPACE.Runtime.InteropServices.BuildTasks package from NuGet. Please see Build Tasks in the dscom README. Once you've added the package, your .csproj file will contain a new ItemGroup with the default settings. You should not have to change anything in there to generate the TLB.
If you want to use/test the assembly on your machine, you can use the dscom32 to register the TLB:
dscom32 tlbregister "D:\.NET Projects\Development\COM host\ComHostTest\bin\x86\Debug\net8.0\ComHostTest.tlb"

This should return:

Type library was registered successfully

To register the TLB using the build task, you can use DsComRegisterTypeLibrariesAfterBuild in your .csproj. See the parameters section of the dscom README.
Adding Reference in VB6
Finally, in VB6, open the References window and locate your library:

You should now be able to see and create an instance of your class in IntelliSense:

Run your VB6 code to make sure everything is working. You should be good to go at this point.
If you get the following error, you have not properly registered the <your project>.comhost.dll:


Run-time error '-2147221164 (80040154)': Class not registered

Updating your DLL
If you need to make changes to your DLL:

If the interface hasn't changed, you only need to rebuild your DLL.
If the interface has changed, you will need to create a new TLB and  register it using dscom32.

Deployment
You can create a setup project using the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022 Extension. Use the 'Extensions > Manage Extensions' menu item to install it if you do not already have it.
These instructions are based on this Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension and .NET article.
Your main concern here is to register the TLB and <your project>.comhost.dll files as has been done above.

In your Class Library project, setup a Publish profile first. This will handle generating the files you want to deploy (including any dependencies your DLL might have). You can do this by right-clicking the project name in the Solution Explorer and selecting 'Publish...' Create a profile with the following options:



Right-click the Setup project name and add a Project Output group. Select Publish Items in the 'Add Project Output Group' window and click OK.
Click the 'Publish Items from ' item in the Setup project and set the PublishProfilePath property to the Publish profile you created in step 1.
Add the TLB file to the Setup project by right-clicking the setup project name in Solution Explorer and selecting 'Add > File...' in the context menu.
Select the TLB file in the setup project and set the Register property to vsdrfCOM.
Add the <your project>.comhost.dll also, even though it will be included in the Publish profile. This will let you control the Register property for that file.
Select the <your project>.comhost.dll file and set the Register property to vsdrfCOMSelfReg.
Build the setup project. You will get two warnings about Two or more objects have the same target location and Unable to create registration information for file named '<your project>.comhost.dll' but you can ignore these.

In the Publish profile, if you are using Framework-dependent Deployment mode, you can setup Prerequisites in your Setup project to make sure the correct .NET runtime is installed.
Notes

The order in which you register the TLB and <your project>.comhost.dll does not matter, but they both must happen.
The <ComHostTypeLibrary Include="ComHostTest.tlb" Id="1" /> line in the project file mentioned in the question text is not necessary.
This also works for WPF Class Library projects.
If you use Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke to update WPF view models, you might run into unexpected Null Reference exceptions when running your code in VB6/VBA since Application.Current is null.

All credit goes to Simon Mourier.

@SimonMourier in testing different steps, I found that having <ComHostTypeLibrary Include="ComHostTest.tlb" Id="1" /> in the project file is not necessary for VB6 to use the library.

I have nothing to add but just want to thank you @Étienne Laneville for providing such a detailed question and answer when you found out what the problem was so that others can benefit from your findings. Simply upvoting your answer felt like it didn't do justice to the effort you did put in. Much appreciated!

@HelO'Ween thank you. It's always a pleasure to give back to the Stack Overflow community. I hope this answer can indeed help others since there isn't much documentation on this matter and it's not easy to understand how everything interacts. Simon's answers had already provided the essentials but I wanted to share extra details.

I haven't tried this but was surprised that the TLB and the DLL both have to be registered during deployment? I thought the TLB was essentially a compile-time dependency for VB6 clients.

@StayOnTarget the <project name>comhost.dll doesn't really contain the type library information it seems. It always has a date of 1/18/2024, even if you make changes to the interface which you would expect should trigger some update to the DLL.
